Different rotation directions caused by view orientation
I use pyhton "bpy.ops.transform.rotate()" to rotate the right angled pipe I made
Set my transform orientation to Normal and Axis to Z.
When I change my perspective from small to large, I find that when I look down from the top, the object rotates clockwise; Looking up from the bottom, the rotation direction changes to counterclockwise.
How can I set it to rotate clockwise from any angle
